# Specialize class templated on constrained non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Let's consider the following code for compile-time evaluation of the factorial function:

```
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral auto num>
struct factorial {
    constexpr static auto val{num * factorial<num - 1>::val};
};

// Note: This only specializes the class for (int)0
template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    constexpr static auto val{1};
};

// ...

factorial<4>::val;  // Ok: 24
factorial<4u>::val; // error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900
                    // This makes sense: There's no factorial<0u> specialization.
```

Is there a way to introduce specialization `factorial<0>` for all integral types (i.e. for all the types that satisfy `std::integral`)?

Of course, I'd like to avoid actually writing out specializations `factorial<0u>`, `factorial<0l>`, and so on.

Comment: How about no specialization, simply constexpr if and constexpr lambda?

Comment: @lorro I know I can use a `constexpr` function to evaluate the factorial. I'm just trying to find out if there's a way to introduce a "base case" for a constrained non-type template for all types that satisfy a  concept.

Comment: fwiw, same as in the answer in good old arcance and verbose C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/8zfEefroW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of explicitly specializing for specifically `0` (i.e. an `int` with value `0`), you can partially specialize for any value which compares equal to `0`:

```cpp
template <std::integral auto I> requires (I == 0)
struct factorial<I> {
    static constexpr auto val = 1;
};
```

which if you prefer can also be spelled this way:

```cpp
template <class T, T I> requires (I == 0)
struct factorial<I> {
    static constexpr auto val = 1;
};
```

but I don't think there's a way to deduce `T{0}` as the value.

Comment: Noice! I reached for an extra `class = void` parameter to add the condition. Gotta unlearn that.